# w3wp.exe high memory usage yet low managed memory usage?

Tags: asp.net, iis, dump

On one of our production servers, w3wp.exe uses >600 MB private memory for an ASP.NET Core app.

I did a managed memory dump with `dotnet-gcdump` yet that one one shows about ~23 MB memory usage from managed objects. I also took a full memory dump but didn't see high memory usage by anything I could access.

Doing the gcdump should have cleaned up any unused memory, right? So something is still actively using all these MBs?

What could be going on here?

Comment: What are the file sizes of those dumps? If you are sure there might be native memory leak, use Debug Diag to track that down, https://www.tessferrandez.com/blog/2010/01/14/debugging-native-memory-leaks-with-debug-diag.html

Comment: This is a very generic issue, there is no specific cause for this, so you need to debug the cause using IIS Debug Diagnostics Tool, this tool will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem. but this is a very complicated process, I suggest you open a [support ticket](https://support.microsoft.com) for this, microsoft engineers will help analyse the dump file & try to find the root cause.